# How to update the first row of a table that contains duplicate IDs and update all unique ID with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains duplicates and uniques id. I want to add 10 cents to all transaction fees and 10 cents to the first row of ever order that is duplicated for example:

```
What i start with:
order# Fee    
123    5    
123    4    
111    3
122    5

what I should get: 

order# Fee     
123    5.1    --duplicates
123    4.0    --should not have 10 cents. 
111    3.1
122    5.1
```

I tried using the code below but it updates every order#

```
-- updates table adds 10 cents to the first order of each duplicate and every unique order
update ebaytemp
set [transaction fees] = [transaction fees] +.10
from (SELECT [order#] 
from ebaytemp
GROUP BY order#
HAVING COUNT(order#) > 1) as E
```

Comment: First row based on what? If there's two entries with `123`, should the `5` or `4` be updated? Do you have something like a `date_entered` or auto-incrementing id column we could base the "first-row" on?

Comment: The frustrating thing is the duplicates have no unique ID even the timestamp is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `datetime` or `timestamp` column which keeps track of when the transactions were entered (how could you not?), you could base your "first row" off of that column and use:

```
UPDATE ebaytemp a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ordernum, MIN(date_entered) AS minentered
    FROM ebaytemp
    GROUP BY ordernum
) b ON a.ordernum = b.ordernum AND a.date_entered = b.minentered
SET a.fee = a.fee + 0.10
```